# Derivations and algebraic extensions in characteristic zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $k\subseteq   L$ be fields of characteristic *zero*. Show that the following
conditions are equivalent:

**(1)** $L$ is algebraic over $k$.

**(2)** For every derivation $d$ of $k$ there exists a unique derivation $D$ of $L$ such that $D_{|k} = d$.

**(3)** If $\delta$ is a $k$-derivation of $L$, then $\delta = 0$.

Comment: The first sentence of your question should not be the title of the question. Could you change the title (using the "edit" button) so that it explains briefly what is your question about?

Comment: For (1) $\Rightarrow$ (2), you might first try the special case when $[L : k]$ is finite.  In that case, you can write $L = k[a]$ for some $a \in L$.

Then any derivation of $L$ is completely determined by its effect on $a$.  This takes care of uniqueness.

Comment: Your edit, @ab_kushal, completely destroyed the question. **Please** do not do that.

Answer (score 8):

$(1)\implies (2)$:
Assume $L/k$ is algebraic and let $d\colon k\to k$ be a derivation.
Let $\alpha\in L$ and $f(X)=\sum_{j=0}^n a_j X^j\in k[X]$ its minimal polynomial. Then for any derivation $D\colon L\to L$ with $D|_k=d$ it is *necessary* that 
$$\begin{align}0&=D(0)\\&=D(f(\alpha))\\&=D\left(\sum_{j=0}^n a_j\alpha ^j\right)\\&=\sum_{j=0}^n D(a_j\alpha^j)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n (d(a_j)\alpha^j+ja_j\alpha^{j-1}D(\alpha))\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n d(a_j)\alpha^j + D(\alpha)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(j+1)a_{j+1}\alpha^j\\
&=d(f)(\alpha)+D(\alpha)f'(\alpha)\end{align}$$
As $\deg f'=\deg f-1$ (we are using characteristic zero here!), we must have $f'(\alpha)\ne 0$ and conclude that $$\tag1D(\alpha)=-\frac{d(f)(\alpha)}{f'(\alpha)}.$$ This shows **uniqueness** of $D$.

On the other hand, for fixed $\alpha$ consider the $k$-linear map $\delta\colon k[X]\to L$, $g\mapsto d(g)(\alpha)+g'(\alpha)D(\alpha)$ (with $D(\alpha)$ given by $(1)$).
We have $\delta(a)=d(a)$ for all $a\in k$, and $\delta(f)=0$, and $$\tag2\begin{align}\delta(gh)&=d(gh)(\alpha)+(gh)'(\alpha)D(\alpha)\\&=d(g)(\alpha)h(\alpha)+g(\alpha)d(h)(\alpha)+(g'(\alpha)h(\alpha)+g(\alpha)h'(\alpha))D(\alpha)\\&=\delta(g)h(\alpha)+\delta(h)g(\alpha)\end{align}$$
so that $\delta$ is zero for all multiples of $f$, which means that it factors over $k(\alpha)$, giving us a linear map $\tilde \delta\colon k(\alpha)\to L$ with $\tilde\delta|_k=d$ and that is a derivation because of $(2)$. By the usual Zorn's lemma argument, we find that there exists a derivation on $L$ that extends $d$.

$(2)\implies (3)$: $\delta$ and the trivial derivation on $L$ are both extensions of the trivial derivation on $k$. By uniqueness, we conclude $\delta=0$.

$(3)\implies (1)$:
Let $K=\bar k\cap L$ and assume $K\ne L$, say $\alpha\in L\setminus K$ is transcendental.
Define $\delta\colon K(\alpha)\to L$ by $\delta(\frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)})=\frac{f'(\alpha)g(\alpha)-f(\alpha)g'(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)^2}$, note that this can again be extended to all of $L$ and id zero on $k$. From $(3)$ and $\delta(\alpha)=1$, arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Very nice proof and explained nicely

Comment: Where have you shown the existence of D

Comment: @Hagen while proving $(1) \implies (2)$, why is $\delta$ a $k$-linear map? $\delta(ag)=d(ag)(\alpha)+(ag)'(\alpha)D(\alpha)=d(a)g(\alpha)+ad(g)(\alpha)+ag'(\alpha)D(\alpha) = d(a)g(\alpha)+a\delta(g)$. There is an extra term $d(a)g(\alpha)$, no?